# How can I traverse a linked list that can not only include loops, but also multiple links from a single node? (VB6)

Tags: graph, vb6, traversal

I've got a linked list made out of `NODE_`'s.  These nodes do not actually point to other nodes, but rather to a linked list of `NODELINK_`'s, which store connected nodes.

This allows for the formation of irregular graphs, such as:

```
N------N---------N-------N
      / \        |        \
     /   \       N---N-----N
    /     \      |    \    |  
   N-------N-----N     N---N
```

You get the idea.  Very dynamic data.  A typical node may look like so:

```
NOODE_1 -> NODELINK_1 -> NODELINK_2 -> NODELINK_3 -> NULL
               |             |             |
               V             V             V
             NODE2_        NODE3_        NODE4_
```

A problem arises when it comes to traversing such a graph.  Making my way around the graph is easy enough, but how can I make sure I don't find myself stuck traversing a loop within the graph (NOTE: It is unsafe to assume that the head will be a part of this loop, so your typical "circular linked list traversal" algorithm won't cut it here), and how can I make sure to know when a node has been processed before?

The only thing I can come up with is setting a flag within each node, indicating that it has already been processed.  This seems sort of like a hackjob, but I can't think of any other way to do this that I would consider reasonable.  Am I wrong?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a [Graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).
Setting a `visited` flag with each node is definitely a common approach e.g. both the [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode) and [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode) algorithms at Wikipedia `mark` the visited nodes.

Comment: +1. Do not attempt to reinvent algorithms that have been very well researched.

Answer (score 3):

The only other way I can think of doing it is to keep a data structure such as a `Dictionary` to list those nodes that you have already visited, and test membership before visiting a node you've already visited.  That would avoid you having to create extra fields within your nodes.

Comment: +1, I like the keeping the tracking of which nodes have been visisted seperate from the nodes/nodelinks themselves.  It is the visitor/iterator that cares about that information so he should carry that data with him.  Seperation of concerns.

Comment: And as an aside, ObjPtr works great a key in the Dictionary for objects that otherwise don't have a good key.